# Inconsistent changes to CoreData

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a function where I'm saving to core data, but the new entry disappears almost every time the function is run, unless a specific different view happens to be open, in which case the change persists.

Here's the general code for the save function:

```
        appDel = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
        context = appDel!.managedObjectContext!
        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "myEntity")
        var results: NSArray = context!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

        localArray = results[item!].valueForKey("key") as NSMutableArray
        localArray.addObject(objectToSave)
        results[item!].setValue(localArray, forKey: "key")

        context!.save(nil)
```

Comment: Can you include your code in your question? It will be easier for others to provide an answer if you give details.

Comment: Are you saving the core data using `context.save(nil)` ?

Comment: I've added the general code for the function that's supposed to be saving the data. It seems to be random as to whether or not it decides to save.